# Why does the accordion open upwards with "flex-direction:column"?

Tags: javascript, flexbox, accordion

My layout consist of 2 columns, the left side has text and the right side has an accordion. The right side has been positioned with "flex-direction" to appear on top of the left side, but this causes the accordion within the right side to open upwards in stead of downwards.

How do I get the accordion in the right side to always open downwards when the parent div uses "flex-direction: column"?

```js
var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("label");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
  acc[i].onclick = function() {
    this.classList.toggle("active");
    this.nextElementSibling.classList.toggle("show");
  }
}
```

```css
.stuff {
  background: #ebeef2;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.left,
.right {
  width: 100%;
}

.left {
  order: 2;
  background: blue;
}

.right {
  order: 1;
  background: green;
}

.label {
  font-size: 2em;
  font-weight: bold;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: relative;
  -webkit-transition: all 300ms ease;
  -moz-transition: all 300ms ease;
  -ms-transition: all 300ms ease;
  -o-transition: all 300ms ease;
  transition: all 300ms ease;
}

.content {
  max-height: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  -webkit-transition: all 300ms ease;
  -moz-transition: all 300ms ease;
  -ms-transition: all 300ms ease;
  -o-transition: all 300ms ease;
  transition: all 300ms ease;
  padding: 1em;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.content.show {
  opacity: 1;
  max-height: 100%;
}

.label:after {
  content: '+';
  font-size: 32px;
  right: 10px;
  top: 0;
  position: absolute;
  font-weight: 100;
}

.label.active:after {
  content: '-';
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="stuff">In ridens invenire sit. Vel ponderum vulputate ex, mel no erant dissentias interpretaris. Amet dicat possit vel eu, habeo vivendum senserit duo no. Duo ne alii facete inciderint.Cum aliquam persecuti cu, in lorem dicit sonet vix, est soluta noster ex.
  An nam novum verear antiopam, nominati moderatius vel at. Pro quis impetus consequuntur in, autem augue deleniti eos cu, sea cu quis integre pertinax. Ut vitae mucius vix, ei eos meis ludus. Reque facilisis ex mel, sea in tota lobortis disputationi.
  Sed quas clita saepe te, te mollis vocent sed. In ridens invenire sit. Vel ponderum vulputate ex, mel no erant dissentias interpretaris. Amet dicat possit vel eu, habeo vivendum senserit duo no. Duo ne alii facete inciderint.Cum aliquam persecuti cu,
  in lorem dicit sonet vix, est soluta noster ex. An nam novum verear antiopam, nominati moderatius vel at. Pro quis impetus consequuntur in, autem augue deleniti eos cu, sea cu quis integre pertinax. Ut vitae mucius vix, ei eos meis ludus. Reque facilisis
  ex mel, sea in tota lobortis disputationi. Sed quas clita saepe te, te mollis vocent sed. In ridens invenire sit. Vel ponderum vulputate ex, mel no erant dissentias interpretaris. Amet dicat possit vel eu, habeo vivendum senserit duo no. Duo ne alii
  facete inciderint.Cum aliquam persecuti cu, in lorem dicit sonet vix, est soluta noster ex. An nam novum verear antiopam, nominati moderatius vel at. Pro quis impetus consequuntur in, autem augue deleniti eos cu, sea cu quis integre pertinax. Ut vitae
  mucius vix, ei eos meis ludus. Reque facilisis ex mel, sea in tota lobortis disputationi. Sed quas clita saepe te, te mollis vocent sed. In ridens invenire sit. Vel ponderum vulputate ex, mel no erant dissentias interpretaris. Amet dicat possit vel
  eu, habeo vivendum senserit duo no. Duo ne alii facete inciderint.Cum aliquam persecuti cu, in lorem dicit sonet vix, est soluta noster ex. An nam novum verear antiopam, nominati moderatius vel at. Pro quis impetus consequuntur in, autem augue deleniti
  eos cu, sea cu quis integre pertinax. Ut vitae mucius vix, ei eos meis ludus. Reque facilisis ex mel, sea in tota lobortis disputationi. Sed quas clita saepe te, te mollis vocent sed.</div>

<div class="container">
  <div class="left">Left Side</div>
  <div class="right">
    <div class="label">Label 1</div>
    <div class="content">Content 1</div>

    <div class="label">Label 2</div>
    <div class="content">Content 2</div>

    <div class="label">Label 3</div>
    <div class="content">Content 3</div>

    <div class="label">Label 4</div>
    <div class="content">Content 4</div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="stuff">In ridens invenire sit. Vel ponderum vulputate ex, mel no erant dissentias interpretaris. Amet dicat possit vel eu, habeo vivendum senserit duo no. Duo ne alii facete inciderint.Cum aliquam persecuti cu, in lorem dicit sonet vix, est soluta noster ex.
  An nam novum verear antiopam, nominati moderatius vel at. Pro quis impetus consequuntur in, autem augue deleniti eos cu, sea cu quis integre pertinax. Ut vitae mucius vix, ei eos meis ludus. Reque facilisis ex mel, sea in tota lobortis disputationi.
  Sed quas clita saepe te, te mollis vocent sed. In ridens invenire sit. Vel ponderum vulputate ex, mel no erant dissentias interpretaris. Amet dicat possit vel eu, habeo vivendum senserit duo no. Duo ne alii facete inciderint.Cum aliquam persecuti cu,
  in lorem dicit sonet vix, est soluta noster ex. An nam novum verear antiopam, nominati moderatius vel at. Pro quis impetus consequuntur in, autem augue deleniti eos cu, sea cu quis integre pertinax. Ut vitae mucius vix, ei eos meis ludus. Reque facilisis
  ex mel, sea in tota lobortis disputationi. Sed quas clita saepe te, te mollis vocent sed. In ridens invenire sit. Vel ponderum vulputate ex, mel no erant dissentias interpretaris. Amet dicat possit vel eu, habeo vivendum senserit duo no. Duo ne alii
  facete inciderint.Cum aliquam persecuti cu, in lorem dicit sonet vix, est soluta noster ex. An nam novum verear antiopam, nominati moderatius vel at. Pro quis impetus consequuntur in, autem augue deleniti eos cu, sea cu quis integre pertinax. Ut vitae
  mucius vix, ei eos meis ludus. Reque facilisis ex mel, sea in tota lobortis disputationi. Sed quas clita saepe te, te mollis vocent sed. In ridens invenire sit. Vel ponderum vulputate ex, mel no erant dissentias interpretaris. Amet dicat possit vel
  eu, habeo vivendum senserit duo no. Duo ne alii facete inciderint.Cum aliquam persecuti cu, in lorem dicit sonet vix, est soluta noster ex. An nam novum verear antiopam, nominati moderatius vel at. Pro quis impetus consequuntur in, autem augue deleniti
  eos cu, sea cu quis integre pertinax. Ut vitae mucius vix, ei eos meis ludus. Reque facilisis ex mel, sea in tota lobortis disputationi. Sed quas clita saepe te, te mollis vocent sed.</div>
```

Comment: I'm afraid I'm unable to get your code snippet to appear as you describe. I see a blue section down below the green section, but the labels of the green section always seem to expand down when clicked.

Comment: @Jhecht Try expanding the snippet to full screen, reduce the window width to about 500 pixel, and scroll to the first ".label" div with it near the top of the viewport. That should cause it to expand upwards.

Comment: I had expanded it full screen. I still see blue section below green section.